# How to run particular protractor test case from command prompt

Tags: protractor

I am successfully able to run the protractor scripts. Below is the protractor.config.js file which I am using to run the protractor scripts.

```
var Jasmine2Reporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

var jReporter=new Jasmine2Reporter({
    dest: './protractor-result', 
    fileName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    'testCaseOne.spec.js'   // Hardcoded to run single script.
    '*.spec.js'            // to run all scripts.

  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',

  framework: 'jasmine2',

};
```

I am successfully able to run the protractor scripts. Below is the protractor.config.js file which I am using to run the protractor scripts
To run above file, I used below command.

```
$ npm run protractor
```

My Expectation:
Now, I would like to run the single protractor script from command prompt. How this can be achieved? This will be useful when I will try to run the protractor test cases from any test management tool.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Additionally to the given answers, you can use suites, which are sets of specs:

You can have suites which consist only of one spec.
You can run particular spec like this:

```
protractor --suite=my-suite-name
```

Also you can temporarily exclude suite or spec in Jasmine using `xdescribe` and xit (just type x before describe or it).

Also you can focus on particular suite or spec in Jasmin using `fdescribe` and `fit` (just type f before `describe` or `it`).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes,   protractor --suite=my-suite-name    command is working fine for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your link points at a premium site. It offers no info to those who aren't willing to pay money.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --specs='specs/run-just-this-spec.js'
```

If you want to run a specific test you need use jasmine2 and pass the `grep` option. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/19139272d190dd9c1888d9c3fc2f480f7c6c8edb/docs/jasmine-upgrade.md

Comment: In case you need to run multiple specs in this fashion: protractor protractor.conf.js --specs='myfirstspec.js','mysecondspec.js'

Answer (score 1):

Use the node.js [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) object.

```
    var w00t = process.env.TESTED || '*';

    exports.config = {
     allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

     specs: [
      w00t + '.spec.js'
     ],
```

Prepend **TESTED=testCaseOn** when you start protractor to execute the desired spec. To execute all scripts add nothing so that ***.spec.js** will be called.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did exact settings above and executed below command "npm run protractor -TESTED=testcaseone". However it has executed all the test cases. Not sure why. Can you pls help me.

Comment: FYI..... when I tried to get the value of {console.log(process.env.TESTED);} it is giving the value as undefined. How to solve this? May be this is the problem at my end.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Try to call the TESTED variable at the beginning  of the command: TESTED=testCaseOne npm run protractor.

Comment: It is giving me below error message    'TESTED' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Durgesh The right command to execute **after having made the changes** (mentioned by @mschoe) will be
`TESTED=name-of-your-test npm run protractor`.
Where "name-of-your-test" is taken from "name-of-your-test.spec.js"

Comment: Please note that the `specs` array is RELATIVE TO THE DIRECTORY OF THE CONFIG. So if you have `src/protractor.conf.js` and `src/specs/spec1.js` - if your config has `specs: [ 'src/specs/spec*.js' ]` it will fail and say `pattern src/specs/spec*.js did not match any files`. To fix it you should have instead: `specs: [ 'specs/spec*.js' ]`